httpd rewriting only query string key
I have a user-friendly URL that I rewrite to one of my internal services, which in turn makes a query to a 3rd party service. The 3rd party service returns some data and the new query parm foo1=bar back to the original URL. Of course my rewrite catches the same friendly URL and sends it to the backend service, and it knows to do something else if it gets that query parm.
And now they changed the 3rd party service on me, and the new one uses the query parm foo2=bar. I also don't want to preserve foo1=bar with QSA. I can't be sure where foo2=bar will appear in the query string, and I can't be sure what will follow in %{REQUEST_URI} other than if something does follow, that portion of the URI is retained unchanged. The value for foo2 will remain the same as foo1 (bar), only the key will change. Having read that mod_rewrite doesn't really parse query strings, I'm hoping someone can tell me that it's possible.
The somewhat childish attempt of a guy who used to be good at this sort of thing follows:
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} foo1 RewriteRule ^friendlyURL(.*)\?(.*)foo1(.*) ^serviceURL$1\?$2foo2$3
I remember enough to be pretty sure that won't work, so I haven't mucked up my programmers' development environment with it. Twenty years ago this would have been a piece of cake, but now in my 60s and needing to do only occasional Apache work, I am befuddled.

Oh, and they tell me this, direct quote:
We spoke with ThirdParty, and the only way to make this ticket functional is to make sure that we provide "foo2" in the query params. But google PLA specs require that we have "foo1" for the links they provide for PLA click-throughs and social media.

Correct, the rewriting module does not "parse" the query string, reason is that there is no definition about the structure of such a string, not on protocol level. That is up to the application logic. The rewriting module treats the query string as a string. You certainly can separate a specific "parameter" in that string by means of a regular expression and capturing groups that capture everything but that specific parameter.
